# Using Optional for validation of input method parameters

Tags: java, validation, null, guava, nullable

I am wondering what is the best way of checking potentially null method arguments.

First reasonable approach is with guava:

```
String validatedValue= Optional.fromNullable(input).or("defaultValue");
```

Second reasonable approach is with regular java. It might have advantage of being easy to understand for someone who does not know guava. However it still shows "low-level" code.

```
String validatedValue= input !=null ? input : "empty";
```

Or third approach. On the one hand looks nice in main method. On the other it potentially spawns a lot of small private methods.

```
String validatedValue = getValidatedValue(input); //this private method will contain option two
```

For now it seems that second or third approach is better and Optional should not be used in this case. Could someone tell what is best practice in this case?

Comment: That doesn't validate the argument. It silently replaces a null value with a default value. To validate it, use `Preconditions.checkNotNull()`. If an argument should not be null, then it should not be null, and an exception should be thrown to tell the caller code that it's buggy.

Comment: I've voted to close as opinion-based. I suspect most programmers would err towards option 1, but that's just my *opinion* :-)

Comment: @JBNizet Well, actually null is allowed in this case, but should be replaced by default value.

Comment: Then also consider providing an overloaded method not taking the nullable argument, and making the argument mandatory in the method which takes it. This is often cleaner and more robust.

Comment: That is not possible in this case. It is web service with insane amount of parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would not call this "validation", the preferred method for supplying *deafult if null* is similar to #2 (if not #2 itself) - using Guava's [`Objects.firstNonNull`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T)) (since Guava 18 it's placed in [`MoreObjects`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T))):

```
String value = Objects.firstNonNull(input, "empty"); // MoreObjects since 18.0
```

which internally does:

```
return first != null ? first : checkNotNull(second);
```

With static import it's just:

```
String nonNullValue = firstNonNull(input, "empty");
```

but which one will you use is just a matter of preference.

P.S. I'd use `Optional` **only** in one case - [if you want lazy evaluated default](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or(com.google.common.base.Supplier)), but with strings it isn't a case. Private method only for null check is overkill, but if you have other assumptions about value, it's generally considered a good practice to use small private methods with meaningful names for this (see [Clean Code by Uncle Bob](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)).

Comment: Nice, I have not knew about firstNonNull. Thank you.